# Changing folder default batch site in Plone

Tags: plone

In Plone the default folder_contents etc. views display 20 items per page. This is too small number for most of our use cases. How to increase this number to 100?

Answer (score 3):

See https://dev.plone.org/ticket/8115:

> The number of items shown by default in the foldercontents is hardcoded in a BrowserView: [tableview.py](https://github.com/plone/plone.app.content/blob/master/plone/app/content/browser/tableview.py). Although I think it's a good default, I find it frustratingly small for some of my websites. I would suggest to move this value to a new property in site_properties.

You'll have to edit [`tableview.py`](https://github.com/plone/plone.app.content/blob/master/plone/app/content/browser/tableview.py), I think.

Comment: Yeah, this is something we really should move to site_properties.  Why not just do it + issue a pull request?  Seems too small for a PLIP to me.